# Can't open exported data

Tags: qgis

I downloaded data here: https://nycopendata.socrata.com/dataset/Pavement-Edge/gydf-ksfn

I opened this up in QGIS but when I export it I can't open it up in another GIS program called indiemapper. Perhaps I'm not exporting it correctly with proper projection? Can someone run down the proper way to export so I won't run into problems down the line?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the other program?

Comment: indiemapper is the only other program I'm using besides QGIS. That's all I have.

Comment: indiemapper "Files under 10 MB work best." NYC Pavement_Edge is 400MB uncompressed - you need to reduce the file size or the area of interest.